# Не получается добавиться данные в таблицу MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Пытался заполнить таблицу данными в MySQL, вылетела вот такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что пошло не так и что с этим делать

Comment: Там в ошибке прямо так и сказано "Duplicate column name 'last_name'", что в переводе на русский означает "Дублируется имя колонки 'last_name'" И действительно, вы пытаетесь создать таблицу в которой две колонки называются 'last_name'. Колонки в таблице должны быть названы по разному, так что удалите или переименуйте одну из колонок 'last_name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не осилили вбить текст ошибки в переводчик?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Только начинаю работать с SQL, поэтому посмотрел только то, что было выделено